# My magento admin panel goes to a unexpected url localhost/magento/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/d0635adba364ac457fb10aa4f6147

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, admin

I have just uploaded Magento on localhost and its url is simply this (localhost/magento) but when I go on its admin part i.e (localhost/magento/admin) part url redirects to a very complicated & unexpected url i.e (http://localhost/magento/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/d0635adba364ac457fb10aa4f6147b02c983c632402595b88482d7956d7accf0/), Please help me out that how can overcome from this problem.??? I have earlier uploaded its previous version but then i have not face this type of problem but that i had uploaded directly on server not on localhost.Please help somebody I am in huge confusion that what should i do next.

Comment: This is not a problem. It is good adding secret key to URL for preventing CSRF attacks. **Add Secret Key to URLs** is a built in security option by Magento. Magento recommends to leave this option enabled.You can take a look here - 
`System -> Configuration -> Admin -> Security -> Add Secret Key to URLs`

Comment: A very complicated and **expected** URL, that ugly key is there to keep you from getting hacked. First time I've seen somebody have a problem with seeing it, most people expect it. Magento admin and install questions belong over on magento.stackexchange btw.